# not able to configure and install java-gnome bindings on fedora 16 due to gtksourceview

Tags: fedora, gnome, gtksourceview

I am trying to install the java-gnome development bindings on my desktop running fedora 16. one of the dependency for it to work is 'gtksourceview'>=2.91. I tried to install it through yum repository and also by compiling the source code but on running './configure' for java-gnome package, none of them is being accepted.

The output is :

Check for required system libraries:
 - Cairo                           found

- GLib                            found
- GTK+                            found
- Pango                           found
- RSVG                            found
- ATK                             found
- GtkSourceView                    not found!

Comment: Did you install the gtksourceview3-devel package as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'gtksourceview >= 2.91' is the GTK+ 3 version and it is in the gtksourceview3 package; for development files you'll need to install gtksourceview3-devel.